# How to set the degradation version for IE11 running in enterprise mode to something other than IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, sharepoint-2013

Our company is insistent on running I.E. 11 in enterprise mode to solve certain "security" issues, and as a result, is adding the intranet to the emulation list.

This intranet is currently running Bootstrap 3 and no longer works properly because of this.

Is there a way to tell I.E. 11 in enterprise mode to emulate I.E. 10 or I.E. 11 and not I.E. 8?

Comment: Nom you can't (not tha tI'm aware of anyway). Why not just [remove the site in question from the Enterprise Mode Site List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640685.aspx)? Doing so should cause it to render in standard (IE11) fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Mode Forces page to render in Internet Explorer 8.

Enterprise mode is specifically designed for running Legacy applications on Internet Explorer 8.

If you want your page to render as IE 9 or 8 You can use below Meta Tag in the code.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

To force IE to use Latest Version of Internet Explorer use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Ref
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have used the `edge` meta tag in IE9 before and it has worked even when the compatibility view setting could not be disabled manually. Now in IE11's enterprise mode this does not work, I have not yet tried specifically setting a version instead of using `edge` though